# Get average data based on date, week, month

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset that includes three years data of a factory workers' output. Now I would like to get average output based on date, week, month for example. The problem is the date format is like %d.%m.%Y (day-month-year). My question is how could I keep the date format unchanged while get the expected output.

My dataset is like this (There are many values daily.)

```
date         output 
1.1.2017     261
2.1.2017     152 (Jan.02,2017)
17.1.2017    256
17.1.2017    261
18.1.2017    193
18.1.2017    462
1.2.2017     212 (Feb.1,2017)
3.2.2017     266 (Feb.3,2017)

....


1.3.2018    360
```

The error message I got like this: time data '2017-01-01' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y' (match). FYI, my code is like this when I read the dataset

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%d.%m.%Y').dt.date
df.groupby(['date'],as_index=False).mean()
```

I have tried solve it by googling different solutions. But I can not get the expect result. The output got totally confused between date and month.e.g. 1.2.2017 (Jan.2,2017) was treated as (Feb.1,2017).How can I solve it? Thank you!

Comment: Swap the `%d` and `%m`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You meant change it to Month,date, year? The original dataset is in date.month.year format.

Comment: Try: ```df["date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["date"])``` and let ```pandas``` find out format for you

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski I did like you suggested. It printed out like this: 2017-01-01, then Jan.02,2017 showed as 2017-02-01, Jan.03,2017 showed as 2017-03-01

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine and in fact works well at least for the first four data records. The problem here is that the date format is not consistent from the error you reported. Like others pointed out, letting the pandas find out format for you would solve the problem, i.e. `df["date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["date"])`. But I just feel that this is a little bit tricky or dangerous. I would like to recommend you unify the date format using string operations in Python before any analysis on them. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Fei YaoI guess I need more hint :)

Comment: Hi @smoothy could you provide a sample of your data? I cannot do more only with the data listed above.